# Centering Images like in the Apple Watch menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, gallery

Heyo,

I was wondering if there is a way to `center` images like in the [Apple Watch menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UwXbd.jpg). Let's say I have an Image in the center of `<div id="gallery">`. The `div`'s width and height is the same as on the `content`'s width and height. So when I put another Image into the `div`, the container expands but all Images are still centered.

Usually most galleries would look like this: [image]

or this: [image]

But I want the gallery to look like this: [image]

Is there any way I can produce that with `Javascript/jQuery`, `CSS` and `HTML`?

Here is my current `HTML` code:

```
<div id="gallery">
  <div class="image">
    <img src="image.png">
  </div>
  <div class="image">
    <img src="image.png">
  </div>
  <div class="image">
    <img src="image.png">
  </div>
  ...
</div>
```

And here my current `CSS` code:

```
#gallery {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```

Comment: Yes, you can create this, but keep in mind that StackOverflow is not a coding service. you have to show us your own effort before we can help you.

Comment: Ok ... I updated my question and pasted the code at the bottom.

Answer (score 4):

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.item {
  width: 100px; 
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can use display: flex and justify-content: center to achieve that

Comment: This might work ... yes but it's static. I want to include more or less Images without changing the HTML all the time.

Comment: You can't do that without changing the html. You can add an arbitrary amount of items to each row and the rows can be generated in JavaScript.

Comment: Or you can calculate the positioning of the images in JavaScript but as Carsten stated this is not a coding service

Answer (score 0):

You may please try this simple way with `display:inline-block` property:

```
<html>
<style>
.gallery {
    text-align: center;
}
.image {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background:green;
    display: inline-block;
}
</style>
<body>
<div class="gallery">
  <div class="image"></div>
  <div class="image"></div>
  <div class="image"></div>
</div>  

<div class="gallery">
  <div class="image"></div>
  <div class="image"></div>
  <div class="image"></div>
  <div class="image"></div>
</div>  

<div class="gallery">
  <div class="image"></div>
  <div class="image"></div>
  <div class="image"></div>
  <div class="image"></div>
  <div class="image"></div>
</div>  

<div class="gallery">
  <div class="image"></div>
  <div class="image"></div>
  <div class="image"></div>
  <div class="image"></div>
</div>  

<div class="gallery">
  <div class="image"></div>
  <div class="image"></div>
  <div class="image"></div>
</div>  
</body>
<html>
```